# Issues Switching to Android in Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have developed an Augmented Relity app for iOS in Unity. It has a good performance.
The app has several scenes but one of them is much much larger than the others (about 60 targets).
The app size in iOS (uncompressed) is massive (1.9Gb) becouse it has a lot of media (images, videos, textures and 3D content).

Now I'm switching the platform to Android and I'm having a lot of trouble:
-The loading time to the principal scene is very very high (10 or more minutes) rather than 20 seconds in iOS (iPhone 4).
-The textures of the 3D content turns in black.

Is there a limitation size for a scene in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Maximum memory available on android might differ per device.
Most only have 256 MB of memory available for a single application.

As for texture memory (again different per device), you might want to look at the compression used. Using the android standard ETC [Unity page on Android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html) should improve loading times. Removing Mip Maps would lower memory use and loading but also potentially decrease FPS (depending on wethere they are used or not).

With Android there is also the option to profile through ADB connection within the Unity Profiler, which could help with narrowing down to a more exact cause of the problem.